# Analytics on a subsample based on a running total

Tags: ssas, dax

I'm new to DAX and I have a problem that I don't know how to solve. I simplify it with an artificial example. I'm in the context of a SSAS tabular model.

Let's say I have a factory of "zirkbols" (invented) and a table representing the sales of zirkbols. Each customer bought a different number of zirkbols and gave a rating 1 to 5.
The table looks like this:

[image: Sample data]

with this code to generate it:

```
= DATATABLE(
    "ClientId"; INTEGER; 
    "CountryCode"; STRING;
    "OrderDate"; DATETIME;
    "OrderAmount"; DOUBLE;
    "Rating"; INTEGER;
    {
        {123; "US"; "2018-01-01"; 502; 1};
        {124; "US"; "2018-01-01"; 400; 4};
        {125; "US"; "2018-01-03"; 60; 5};
        {126; "US"; "2018-01-02"; 160; 4};
        {124; "US"; "2018-01-05"; 210; 3};
        {128; "JP"; "2018-01-03"; 22; 5};
        {129; "JP"; "2018-01-07"; 540; 2};
        {130; "JP"; "2018-01-03"; 350; 4};
        {131; "JP"; "2018-01-09"; 405; 4};
        {132; "JP"; "2018-01-09"; 85; 5}
    }
)
```

I need to create measures that give me statistics for the sample of clients that bought 30% of my sales, taken among the most satisfied. This means that I need to rank by "Rating" and sum the "OrderAmounts" until I get at least 30% of the total. This sample are my happy zirkbols owners. For these happy zirkbols owners I would like to know for example their average rating.

I think that this could be easier if I could put the running total of the order amounts in a calculated column, but I would like to give the analyst the possibility to filter for example only the "US" sales and I don't know if this is possible in a calculated column.
On the other hand I suppose that the ranking by rating can be stored in a calculated column (Ranking = RANK.EQ([Rating];ClientOrders[Rating])).

I expect the following result:

[image: Result]

As I said I'm new to SSAS and DAX, so I don't know if I am taking this problem from the wrong angle...

Regards,
Nicola

**P.S. Please see the comments on the accepted answer as well**

Comment: For JP, you picked the ones rated 5 and then the client rated 4 with a lesser amount. For US, you picked the greater amount for the second choice. You should probably choose one approach other unless you want to be solving the knapsack packing problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got some DAX mostly working, but I'll need to come back to it.

In the meantime, here's some of the code:

```
Happy owners amount =
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Orders,
        Orders[CountryCode],
        Orders[ClientId],
        Orders[Rating],
        "Amount", SUM ( Orders[OrderAmount] )
    )
VAR Ranked =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( Summary, "Rank", RANKX ( Summary, Orders[Rating] + 1 / [Amount] ) )
VAR Cumulative =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        Ranked,
        "CumAmt", CALCULATE (
            SUM ( Orders[OrderAmount] ),
            FILTER ( Ranked, [Rank] <= EARLIER ( [Rank] ) )
        )
    )
VAR CutOff =
    MINX (
        FILTER (
            Cumulative,
            [CumAmt]
                > 0.3 * CALCULATE ( SUM ( Orders[OrderAmount] ), ALLSELECTED ( Orders ) )
        ),
        [Rank]
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( FILTER ( Cumulative, [Rank] <= CutOff ), [Amount] )
```

Comment: Hi Alexis, thank you for your answer. I see that the questions as it was posed has a feature that makes it needlessly much harder. If I change the condition "at least 30%" with "at most 30%" it gets much easier to solve. In my real case, since I have a larger sample, the border case of crossing the 30% is not really significant.

Comment: The measure for the average rating I get at the end is:
    averageRating:=
    VAR cumSum = ADDCOLUMNS(
        ClientOrders;
        "CumVal"; SUMX(
            FILTER(
                ClientOrders;
                [Ranking]<EARLIER([Ranking]) || ([Ranking] = EARLIER([Ranking]) && [ClientId] <= EARLIER([ClientId]))
            );
            [OrderAmount]
        );
        "TotVal"; SUM([OrderAmount])
    )
    VAR condSum = ADDCOLUMNS(
        cumSum;
        "CondRat"; IF([CumVal]/[TotVal]<0.3; [Rating]; BLANK())
    )
    return AVERAGEX(condSum; [CondRat])

Comment: I marked your answer as my solution because it solved the main problem I had: I did not know that you could your a table variable (VAR) inside a measurement. Thank you!